# sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input on my code

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Can someone help me understand what's incomplete about my code, no matter what I try I keep getting the sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input. My code is

```
editor = Tk()
editor.title('Edit Record')
editor.geometry('400x400')

#Creating database 
conn = sqlite3.connect('Student_info.db') 
c = conn.cursor()

record_id = delete_box.get()
#Query the database 
c.execute("SELECT * FROM Student_info WHERE oid ="+(record_id))<-----
records = c.fetchall()
```

The line that sublime is referring to is the one I've drawn an arrow to, if anyone could help that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for `execute()` is off.  You should be using a prepared statement as the first parameter, followed by a tuple of parameters as the second function parameter:

```py
record_id = delete_box.get()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM Student_info WHERE oid = %s", (record_id,))
records = c.fetchall()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but even with the code edited it's giving me error sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Comment: @Tim did you forget to use `%` to format the `record_id` into the query, or is `c.execute()` doing that for you?